# How do I deploy my LibGDX game to my website?

Tags: java, html, gwt, libgdx, game-engine

The furthest I've gotten is running it on the browser through the command line. I went into the appropriate directory and used the ./gradlew html:superDev command and then went to the URL localhost:8080 and was able to play my game.
However, what i need to do is put this game onto my website so that anyone can play it on the internet. From what I was able to find on the internet, I compiled my project by "Google" -> "GWT Compile" and then placed the WAR directory contents into my website directory at GoDaddy.com (which is where my website is hosted).
You can see what happens by going to the URL yourself at http://www.vikkalkat.com/war/game.html

Someone please help and tell me how to properly deploy a LIBGDX project to the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gradlew html:superDev` is not appropriate, if you want to distribute the game on a public webserver.

The wiki article [Gradle on the Commandline](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline) has a section, which tells you how to package your app when you want to distribute it. For the HTML backend this is done via `gradlew html:dist`. After that you will have to upload the contents of your `html/build/dist/` folder to your webserver.